# How to know if a task in the crontab actually was executed

Tags: linux, cron

I have a Script that is supposed to be execute by the crontab. How can I verify this at this moment if the task was programmed to be executed several hours ago?

Comment: You could setup the script to output to a log when it's executed by the crontab...

Comment: usually the log file is /var/log/cron

Comment: You can find that information in syslog (if so configured, true on ubuntu with anacron)

Comment: make it send you an email to your phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should modify your crontab file by adding a `MAILTO=<your email here>` before your cron so that you will be emailed the results of the execution. This won't solve your problem of knowing if the script executed in the past, but it may help you avoid this issue in the future. To make sure you get an email, just add an `echo "Running script!"` line to the top of your script.

Comment: You could also use the `logger` command inside your script.